# Apache domain redirect between virtualservers

Tags: apache, redirect, virtual, port, dedicated

I've got one dedicated server which I splitted into more virtual servers.
On main server I use standard port for http (80), but for others I was forced to  set different ports.
But I've got some spare domains.
What is best way to make invisible redirect to another server when user come through specific domain?
I don't want to use iframes or redirect to another website. I would like domain to act like on shared web hostings. But with different servers.

Is it possible to do?
I know that apache gets information about from which domain user came.
I would like to do it with virtual hosts if it's possible.

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName mydomain
ServerAlias mydomain 
some redirection
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mydomain.access.log combined
ServerAdmin myemail
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have access to the server's config, take a look at the [`ProxyPass`, `ProxyPassMatch`, and `ProxyPassReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directives that are part of mod_proxy. You'll need to make sure the module is loaded before you can use these directives.

In general, in your **mydomain** config, say you want to have visitors see the site at `http://myother.domain.com/` when they go to `http://mydomain/other`, you'd just add:

```
ProxyPass /other http://myother.domain.com/
ProxyPassReverse /other http://myother.domain.com/
```

The `ProxyPassReverse` is to ensure proxied location responses get rewritten. For example, if a page at  `http://myother.domain.com/` returned a 301 redirect to `http://myother.domain.com/newimage.gif`, this directive will internal rewrite the response's location from `http://myother.domain.com/newimage.gif` to `http://mydomain/other/newimage.gif`, for it to be proxied again.

If you have cookie domains that also need rewriting, take a look at `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` and `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath`.